# MIDI Outputs for VST Plugin

Tags: midi, vst

I remember this vaguely from the Hypersonic 2 VST instrument.

Basically, it's a normal VST instrument, but if you had it in your project, you can assign its MIDI output (which was equal to the input, except if you had transposition or so active) to the input of another MIDI track, so basically it would just forward all the MIDI events to be used by another synth or whatever.

In Cubase, the output of the instrument was listed next to the physical MIDI inputs in the MIDI input popdown menu, but the "Use All MIDI Inputs" option in the menu did not include Hypersonic's output (it was separated by a menu separator).

I haven't found a way to do that, does anybody know? I guess it's one of those barely documented magic lines...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use c++ but to make a VST plugin that has a MIDI output you need to override the `AudioEffectX::canDo()` function and return `1` to the `sendVstMidiEvent` and possibly `sendVstEvents` canDo's.